# C# Dictionary elementSelector struggles with implicit IEnumerable cast

Tags: linq, ef-core-5.0, c#-9.0, ef-core-6.0

Simple scenario :

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> d2 = d.ToDictionary(
    kv => kv.Key,
    kv => kv.Value // <-- the problem
    );
```

.

```
ERROR  CS0029 : Cannot implicitly convert from List<string> to IEnumerable<string>
```

My (shameful) workaround :

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> d2 = d.ToDictionary(
    kv => kv.Key,
    kv => kv.Value.Where(x => true) // <-- back to being IEnumerable
    );
```

I'm not bold enough to try this and face unforeseen consequences :

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> d2 = d.ToDictionary(
    kv => kv.Key,
    kv => (IEnumerable<int>)kv.Value // <-- explicit cast
    );
```

Any advice?

Comment: `kv.Value.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: I'm unsure why the casting would be any dangerous. If `d` is indeed always a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` I'm not aware of any edge cases where casting a `List<int>` to `IEnumerable<int>` would cause an issue.

Comment: The problem by the way not in the casting between `List<int>` to `IEnumerable<int>`. This cast is safe, the problem is in casting between `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` and `Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>`. The dictionary is not covariant

Comment: Also agree with @ArthurAttout this cast is never dangerous, because `List<int>` implements `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: Why didn't any of you post those comments as the actual answer? You don't like points? :-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> d2 = d.ToDictionary(
    kv => kv.Key,
    kv => kv.Value.Where(x => true).AsEnumerable() // <--
    );
```